# Use Illuminate database

Tags: php, laravel, illuminate-container

I want to use Illuminate database(https://github.com/illuminate/database). Not with Laravel, use only in my php file.
I do

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

$capsule = new Capsule;

$capsule->addConnection([
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'database',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => 'password',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
]);
```

But it seems not working, and don't show any error message. Do I need to require any file? The illuminate directory is in the same directory with my php file.

EDIT:

I can use query now. Like this

```
$users = Capsule::table('users')->where('votes', '>', 100)->get();
```

I don't know how to use model.

User.php

```
class User extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
}
```

My php file

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'User.php';
$users = User::where('status', '=', 1)->get();
```

Got error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function connection() on a non-object in /Users/someone/repos/test/vendor/illuminate/database/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 2472
```

SOLVED:

Everything works fine. Use @majid8911 example https://github.com/mattstauffer/IlluminateNonLaravel
Thank you everyone.

Comment: have you performed composer update?

Comment: try adding `$capsule->setAsGlobal();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

take a look at here I successfully did the same with this tutorial:
https://github.com/mattstauffer/IlluminateNonLaravel

Comment: I saw the codes a while. I can see some models defined in app/Eloquent, but how to use in my php file. Do I need to require any files? What does the public directory do? Thanks

Comment: I use you codes. It's works. I can run $users = UserEncapsulated::all(); However, foreach ($users as $user){ echo $user->name; } not working